# --add-exports command not working for java.util.concurrent package

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, openjdk-17

I'm currently upgrading a project from JDK 11 to 17, and even tho I had previously dealt with the `module java.base does not "opens java.util.concurrent" to unnamed module @6c38726a` error and managed to fix it using the `--add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED` command on the VM options, for some reason it seems that for this project it isn't working.

Dockerfile:

```
ENV JAVA_OPTS="--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED"
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
<jvm.options>--add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED</jvm.options>
</properties
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>${jvm.options}</compilerArgs>
        <optimize>true</optimize>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
```